# PHP - If input Checked use Email $message Template 1 else use Template 2

Tags: php, email, if-statement, payment

First off I'm some what new to PHP and Emails but I need to be able to send Two email template conjunction to if the user has or has not checked the input box. The email function works and has been but I'm completely lost on how to do a If Else statement to swap templates. My question is, why is my console not giving me errors but it's not sending any more.

**The Path needed...**

- User does not have Invoice (Checks input box) > Switch to Template 1
- User has Invoice > Switch to Template 2

  ```
  <p style="margin-top: 10px;">
  If you do not not your Invoice Number please check this box. 
  <input id="check" name="check" type="checkbox" />
  </p>

  ------------------------------------------------------------


  <?php

  $to      = $_POST['email'];
  $subject = 'Subject '       . $_POST['invoice_name'] . ' '
                                              . $_POST['invoice_year'] . ' - '
                                              . $_POST['invoice_number'];                 
  $header = "From: support@website.com" . "\r\n";
  $header .= "Reply-To: support@website.com" . "\r\n";
  $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

  $message = if(isset($_POST['check']) {
      $message = '<html>
                      <body>
                          <h2>Email Template 2</h2>
                          <p>
                              Donec sed odio dui. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
                          <p><b>Name:             </b>' . $_POST['first_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['last_name'] . '</p>
                          <p><b>Invoice #:        </b>' . $_POST['invoice_name'] . ' '
                                                        . $_POST['invoice_year'] . ' - ' 
                                                        . $_POST['invoice_number'] . '</p>
                          <p><b>Date:             </b>' . $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a") . '</p>
                          <p><b>Card Used:        </b> XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-' . $charge->card->last4 . '</p>
                          <p><b>Payment Amount:   </b>$' . $_POST['price'] . '</p>
                          <br/>
                          <p><b>Reminder:</b> Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
                          <br/>
                          <p>http://www.website.com/payment</p>
                      </body>
                  </html>';

  } else {

      $message = '<html>
                      <body>
                          <h2>Email Template 2</h2>
                          <p>
                              Donec sed odio dui. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
                          <p><b>Name:             </b>' . $_POST['first_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['last_name'] . '</p>
                          <p><b>Invoice #:        </b>' . $_POST['invoice_name'] . ' '
                                                        . $_POST['invoice_year'] . ' - ' 
                                                        . $_POST['invoice_number'] . '</p>
                          <p><b>Date:             </b>' . $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a") . '</p>
                          <p><b>Card Used:        </b> XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-' . $charge->card->last4 . '</p>
                          <p><b>Payment Amount:   </b>$' . $_POST['price'] . '</p>
                          <br/>
                          <p><b>Reminder:</b> Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
                          <br/>
                          <p>http://www.website.com/payment</p>
                      </body>
                  </html>';
  };

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

  ?>
  ```

Here's a more simple way to look at it.

```
    <?php if(isset($_POST['check']) {

        $message = ' HAS NO INVOICE ';

    } else {        

        $message = '';

    };

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
?>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: My question is, why is my console not giving me errors but it's not sending any more.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I would do the if/else like this:

```
$message = '';
if( isset($_POST['check']) )
{
    $message = '<html>
                    <body>
                        <h2>Email Template 1</h2>
                        <p>
                            Donec sed odio dui. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
                        <p><b>Name:             </b>' . $_POST['first_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['last_name'] . '</p>
                        <p><b>Invoice #:        </b>' . $_POST['invoice_name'] . ' '
                                                      . $_POST['invoice_year'] . ' - ' 
                                                      . $_POST['invoice_number'] . '</p>
                        <p><b>Date:             </b>' . $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a") . '</p>
                        <p><b>Card Used:        </b> XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-' . $charge->card->last4 . '</p>
                        <p><b>Payment Amount:   </b>$' . $_POST['price'] . '</p>
                        <br/>
                        <p><b>Reminder:</b> Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
                        <br/>
                        <p>http://www.website.com/payment</p>
                    </body>
                </html>';

} else {

    $message = '<html>
                    <body>
                        <h2>Email Template 2</h2>
                        <p>
                            Donec sed odio dui. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
                        <p><b>Name:             </b>' . $_POST['first_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['last_name'] . '</p>
                        <p><b>Invoice #:        </b>' . $_POST['invoice_name'] . ' '
                                                      . $_POST['invoice_year'] . ' - ' 
                                                      . $_POST['invoice_number'] . '</p>
                        <p><b>Date:             </b>' . $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a") . '</p>
                        <p><b>Card Used:        </b> XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-' . $charge->card->last4 . '</p>
                        <p><b>Payment Amount:   </b>$' . $_POST['price'] . '</p>
                        <br/>
                        <p><b>Reminder:</b> Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
                        <br/>
                        <p>http://www.website.com/payment</p>
                    </body>
                </html>';
}
```

Comment: Nothing sadly. I removed everything below " $message = '' " and it worked fine so it's got to be something inside not working right.

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = if(isset($_POST['check']) {
```

Should be changed to just:

```
if(isset($_POST['check']) {
```

since you are setting the message within the if statement

Comment: Still not working. I had " if(isset($_POST['check']) { " before and that's why I added the rest thinking that it was the problem. But so far it's still not working :\ Should I share anything else?

Comment: You could try adding a space after Content-type: in the header.  Check if the mail function is returning true or false.

Comment: I get 'mail is not defined'. My document calls for a Javascript file that calls a php file when the submit button is clicked. But when clicked it calls Stripe payments to pass tokens and if all goes well it will send emails. But the moment I try to add a if(isset()) it breaks. I've tried so many ways yet every time it breaks. But the moment I remove it, it works. Go here to try it out http://www.lepcalendars.com/marco